# I have a php form that I want propagated with the current logged in Microsoft Active Directory Real Name

Tags: php, active-directory

I have a simple intranet form where the user has to enter info for a Time off Request or other for some other internal company use.

I would like to propagate the name field with the current Real Name that is logged in Microsoft Active Directory.  The user has to login on their computer.  Is there a way to pull that Real Name with a php query of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Not automagic based on the person's current domain login, but definitely *THE* tool to use if you're trying to write PHP code aimed at accessing/modifying Active Directory information is the [adLDAP library](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/).

Back to what is (I believe) your actual question, of being able to query the information based on NTLM authentication, you might want to see this article: [Accessing NTLM Secured Resources with PHP](http://blog.thinkphp.de/archives/125-Accessing-NTLM-secured-resources-with-PHP.html)

Answer (score 1):

So just to be clear, there is no method to have the browser or php access the current logged in user Real Name from the MS AD?  A user sits down at his/her chair, logs in using their Real Name, gains access to the intranet/server and all resources they need, but I have no way to access that already logged in user info without running something like LDAP?

Checking out the resources you listed... Thanks for the help